# Question about Thm 3.4.2 in Brian Hall's book in Lie Algebras

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

[image]

My question is regarding the blue highlighted sentence. How does the calculation show that the derivative is the identity though? Shouldn't it be that if $X, Y = 0$, we have $\frac{d}{dt} \Phi(tX, 0)|_{t=0}=0$ instead?

Comment: Do you know that the differential of $\Phi$ is a linear map $d\Phi$ between tangent spaces ?

Comment: No, do you have any resource that I should look up?

Comment: I don't know if the author have explained in the book, or probably he already assumed that the reader should know some basic multivariable calculus before. Good introductory book is Loring Tu's Introduction to Manifolds or (if you dont want to dive into manifolds), look for any good multivariable calculus book such that treat tangent map of a differentiable function such as Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced calculus or Munkres's Analysis on Manifold.

Comment: Sure, but is there any intuitive way I should be looking at it? I think that really don't see how you are supposed to get the identity here

Comment: If you have some background on differential of a map, maybe i would write an answer. But i choose not to at this stage. Maybe someone would help you later. Good luck.